# Can I use the bitmap_allocator in /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/bitmap_allocator.h in cplusplus?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm a newbie on cplusplus, and thanks for answering my questions.

I'm now trying to find some memory pool allocators other than std::allocator, and I've found that there're some allocators in ../version/ext/ folder. (I'm in Linux and I don't know about windows. And I'm using gnu compiler g++-4.7)

I quite found some explanation on GNU:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html
But if I write __gnu_cxx::bitmap_allocator, there'll still be a comile error.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? (Why is the standard allocator not meeting your needs?)

Comment: I was testing my class which provided that the allocator can be replaced. So ... I need a test allocator that meets the standard.

Comment: And ... It's my own fault, silly fault. Sorry for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my own fault... %>_<%. A very silly fault = =.

I did not include the file...

for those who want to know how to use this, code provided as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ext/bitmap_allocator.h>

int main()
{
    __gnu_cxx::bitmap_allocator<int> bit_alloc;
    std::vector<int, __gnu_cxx::bitmap_allocator<int> > v(bit_alloc);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);
    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}//main
```